# bash error popping up in elementary os suddenly

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, syntax-error, elementary-os

`` bash: /home/kartik/.bashrc: line 171: syntax error near unexpected token `apt='apt-fast''
bash: /home/kartik/.bashrc: line 171: `esacalias apt='apt-fast'' ``

It was running fine earlier. It just started popping up recently. I really didn't do much. im new to **elementary os**. I can really use some help right now.
thanks

Comment: So what is the content of `/home/kartik/.bashrc` file? Did you try putting a newline between `esac` and `alias` in `esacalias`?

Comment: you need an enter (newline) after `esac` and before `alias`

Comment: `\`esacalias apt='apt-fast''` quotes are not matching

Comment: The error is right here in the end of the file ```esacalias apt='apt-fast' ``` I tried updating and upgrading but that didnt fixed it hope you guys will figure it out. There's this guy who said it might have been due to his gist which i followed (https://gist.github.com/Surendrajat/418d5fd66876848a7f21870fe09365a7   i think he must have fixed it by now).
he asked me to do a ```nano ~/.bashrc``` and then put a new line between esac and alias or to just ```sed -i -e 's/esacalias/esac\nalias/' ~/.bashrc```. I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: bashrc is on (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SKzaKNgX0-4Sy_uRuZZnIYbVSDpR_r9C)

Comment: @samthegolden I tried that and voila it fixed it! thank to all you guys.

Comment: `esacalias apt='apt-fast'` is two lines. `esac\nalias apt='apt-fast'`